# pass php variables in a bash script

Tags: php, bash, shell

I want to run this script bash

```
#!/bin/bash
# file name: myscript.sh
PROJECT_DIR=$1
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills/cr
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills/cr/corrections
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills/cr/corrections/jpg
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills/cr/corrections/pdf
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills/cr/diagnostic
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills/cr/zooms
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills/data
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills/exports
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills/scans
mkdir $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills/copies
cd $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills
cp ~/file.tex $PROJECT_DIR/PolySkills
```

For the variable "PROJECT_DIR" that represents a path in which I will create folders, I want to retrieve its value from a php variable.
I looked at some examples on the internet and I tried one but it does not work. This is what i used :

```
   chdir('~/');
   $pathtofile = "~/ExportEval/".$NomUE."/".$NomOcc."/".$Numtudiant;
   $directory=$pathtofile."/AMC_Project";
   $output = exec("./myscript $directory");
```

Knowing that the script file "myscript " exists in home "~ /"

thank you for your help :)

I update my question :
I found what is the problem but I don't see what the solution as the variable $NomUE is composed of a sentence separated by spaces it considers that $ 1 is only the first of this sentence if I change $ 1 by $ 2 it takes the second word of that same sentence! I don't understand why it does not take $pathtofile as path !

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do it with just php?

Comment: Yes I will then run AMC commands (a tool that can fix the qcm automatically) so I need a bash script to do that

Comment: I found what is the problem but I do not see what the solution as the variable $NomUE is composed of a sentence separated by spaces it considers that $ 1 is only the first of this sentence if I change $ 1 by $ 2 it takes the second word of that same sentence! I do not understand why it does not take $pathtofile as path !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to always [escape variables](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) before sending them to the command line. Also, `~` has no meaning here and there's no reason to use `chdir()`. Just use a fully qualified pathname instead:

```
<?php
$pathtofile = "/home/someuser/ExportEval/$NomUE/$NomOcc/$Numtudiant";
$directory = escapeshellarg("$pathtofile/AMC_Project");
$output = exec("/home/someuser/myscript $directory");
```

You may have problems running a script in a home directory, and reading from that directory. Best is to put the script in a proper location such as `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: thnak you : i used   $NomUEFile = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$NomUE );
               $NomOccFile = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$NomOcc );
               $NumtudiantFile = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$Numtudiant );    to delete the spaces in the variables

Comment: You don't need to do that. Just use `escapeshellarg`. Since the spaces are in a file path, you're invalidating your path by removing characters.